# What do the symbols next to windows listed in an apps menu indicate?

Tags: macos, dock

When holding click on an app in the dock it will show a list of all windows open. I have noticed there are different symbols next to each window. It seems that a checkmark indicates the active window. I can't figure out or find information on what the diamonds mean and why some windows do not have a symbol. I would like to know what all the symbols mean.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tick shows the current foreground window of that app. The lozenges show windows that have been minimized.

The other windows are just other windows.

A black dot indicates that the window has unsaved changes. Less common in Apple's apps, but you still see it on things like Word.

Comment: "The other windows" can be other windows in the background, but also include previously used, but now closed, windows. Often used by document centric apps.